# Facebook Graph Api RequireCaptcha error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've the following problem. Since ca. one year I've a script running which updates events from my website to my facebook fan page. Last week I've noticed that this isn't running anymore.
I've debugged the facebooks responses and saw that my curl request get following answered by the graph api:

```
stdClass::__set_state(array(
   'error' =>
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'message' => '',
 'type' => 'RequireCaptcha',
  )),
))
```

After several runs and sorting of my events (different variants of sorting) I've figured out that this graph api response comes in the middle of all of the transfers. So I guess that there is no problem with the single events itself, but more an problem with the amount of events my script is publishing?
Is there a spam-check by facebook or sth else?
I cant answer a captcha by api... -.-

hope somebody can help me out of this disaster :|